# C/C++ preprocessor directive check defined and string not empty

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm trying to obtain something like:

```
#if (!defined(SVN_REV) || (SVN_REV==""))
   char svnrev[10]="not found";
#else
   char svnrev[16]=SVN_REV;
#endif
```

to handle the case that the compiler, not finding a particular environment variable, sets:

```
define SVN_REV ""
```

which for me should be treated same as the define is missing.

But it seems that this is not possible, did anybody found a way to achieve the result?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? how do you know?

Comment: Visual C++ is complaining that it is "invalid integer constant expression", didn't try on linux gcc/g++ yet

Comment: No Visual C++ tells that ' define SVN_REV "" '

Comment: Why not char `svnrev[]="not found";` Let it count the characters for you.

Comment: What is "C/C++"? Why is this question tagged C if you are actually writing C++?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I tried to make the question generic to C/C++ because I work in both environments but still I'm interested in considering more restricted solution

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit C++ uses the same preprocessor as C, so the question is the same for both languages.

Answer (score 0):

No, the C preprocessor doesn't compare strings.

You can do:

```
#if !defined SVN_REV
#define SVN_REV "not found"
#endif
const char *svnrev = SVN_REV;
```

To achieve the same effect.

Comment: But this does not cover the case that Visual C++ (which in the case does not find a particular environment variable) defines SVN_REV as an empty string - so it is defined but as empty which for me is like not defined. Probably it is not possible to obtain the result only with preprocessor code.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question... :(